# Creating secondary x-axis for grouped bar chart

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am creating a bar chart using ggplot, and am trying to create a "secondary" x-axis, as it were, by year. The code I have below will duplicate what I am trying to create:

```
library('ggplot2')

d1 <- structure(list(year = c(2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 
                              2011L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 
                              2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2016L, 
                              2016L, 2016L, 2016L), 
                     group = c("Group 1", "Group 2", "Group 4", 
                              "Group 1", "Group 2", "Group 3", "Group 4", "Group 1", "Group 2", 
                              "Group 3", "Group 4", "Group 1", "Group 2", "Group 3", "Group 4", 
                              "Group 1", "Group 2", "Group 3", "Group 4", "Group 1", "Group 2", 
                              "Group 3", "Group 4", "Group 1", "Group 2", "Group 3", "Group 4"), 
                     count = c(111L, 216L, 22L, 125L, 231L, 22L, 57L, 126L, 256L, 
                               22L, 70L, 137L, 302L, 41L, 81L, 132L, 299L, 30L, 108L, 140L, 
                               337L, 22L, 95L, 168L, 383L, 31L, 96L)), 
                .Names = c("year", "group", "count"), 
                row.names = c(3L, 4L, 5L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 32L, 
                              33L, 34L, 35L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 77L, 78L, 
                              79L, 80L, 92L, 93L, 94L, 95L), 
                class = "data.frame")

ggplot(d1, aes(x = group, y = count, group = year, fill = group)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = 'dodge', color = 'black') +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 400, 25),
                     limits = c(-20, 400)) +
  geom_text(aes(x = group, y = 0, group = year, label = year), 
            position = position_dodge(width = .92), size = 4, angle = -90, hjust = -.1) +
  guides(fill = FALSE)
```

Now, this works just fine for my purposes when I am creating a single graph, but I am trying to incorporate a figure such as this into a shiny app where the data ranges wildly, and simply setting the lower y limit to -20 like I did in this example is not an effective way to show the years below the bars.

Is there a way to duplicate what I am doing here without having to resort to using `geom_text` to work around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you've described. I think you are looking for facetted plots.

To create faceted plots, you can used `facet_wrap,facet_grid`. This code snippet should accomplish something similar without having to use `geom_text`.

```
ggplot(d1, aes(x=year,y=count,fill=group)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = 'dodge', color = 'black') +
  facet_wrap(~group) + 
  guides(fill = FALSE) + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 400, 25),
                     limits = c(-20, 400))
```

[image]

Comment: Ahhhhhhh...... of course. Facets will indeed work for me in this particular case. Thanks!